# Sub Shell Redirection Error With Variable ( while .... ) $3 > $testdir/$testfile.log

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection

My scripts executes the sub shell command along the lines of:

```
 ( while ..... ) $3>$testdir/$testfile.log
```

I get the error:

```
line 75: syntax error near unexpected token `$3'
line 75: `    ) $3>$testdir/$testfile.log'
```

I've tried several options, and seems `>` is only happy when it's hard coded number rather than a variable. Am I missing a parenthesis?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the shell syntax only permits something like

`#>'

where `#`is a single digit.

A shell may support multi-digit numbers but the behavior is unspecified by POSIX.

Being able to do variable expansion here would go far beyond the specified syntax.

You may however use `eval` to expand the text and then call the parser again.

Comment: unfortunately `(while ... ) eval $3>....` also error out with the same issue.

Comment: Well I thought it should be obvious that `eval`applies to whole commands and not to fragments from commands. You need to use eval for the whole command.

Comment: would it change the subshell in anyway?
BTW, i tested it and it worked.

Comment: You need to check whether your eval command may be affected by being fed trough the parser for a second time.

Answer (score 1):

Shell syntax is limited: redirection can only be indicated by a single digit immediately before the redirection operator. You can't have multiple digits¹, intervening space, or a digit resulting from a variable expansion.

If you have a file descriptor number in a variable, you can use `eval` to splice it into a shell code snippet which performs a redirection. To avoid putting a large part of your script in an `eval` string, use the `exec` builtin to perform the redirection. For example, if this is the code with a hard-coded file descriptor number

```
( … ) 3>foo
```

then you can use this code to redirect to the file descriptor indicated by the variable `fd`:

```
( eval "exec $fd>foo"; … )
```

¹  <sub>You can only in some shells, which support this as an extension.</sub>